# error when Installing SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

i am trying to install Sonata using installation instruction in sonata official website but when i try to install SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle always i got this

```
Using version ^2.3 for sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle 2.3.3 requires sonata-project/admin-bundle ~2.3@dev -> satisfiable by sonata-project/admin-bundle[2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.10, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7, 2.3.8, 2.3.9, 2.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle 2.3.2 requires sonata-project/admin-bundle ~2.3@dev -> satisfiable by sonata-project/admin-bundle[2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.10, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7, 2.3.8, 2.3.9, 2.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle 2.3.1 requires sonata-project/admin-bundle ~2.3@dev -> satisfiable by sonata-project/admin-bundle[2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.10, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7, 2.3.8, 2.3.9, 2.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle 2.3.0 requires sonata-project/admin-bundle ~2.3@dev -> satisfiable by sonata-project/admin-bundle[2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.10, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7, 2.3.8, 2.3.9, 2.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle ^2.3 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle[2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Please help

Comment: can you post your composer.json file as well?